# Spring MVC form with foreach

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a question about Spring, particularly the MVC component. I have a jsp page which contains the following code.

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="sentenceModelAttribute"
           method="POST" action="sentencemanagement.htm">
       <table class="activity">                
          <tr>
             <th/>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Description</th>
             <th>Action</th>
             <th>Decision</th>
          </tr>

          <c:forEach items = "${model.allSentences}" var="sentence">
          <tr>
             <td><form:radiobutton path="id" value="${sentence.id}"/></td>
             <td>${sentence.id}</td>
             <td>${sentence.description}</td>
             <td>${sentence.action}</td>
             <td>${sentence.decision}</td>
          </tr>
          </c:forEach>

       </table>
       <input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify"/>  
       <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>            
    </form:form>
```

The POST is connected to a method in a controller and this method has an argument sentenceModelAttribute. Currently, this argument has all the values of the object from the selected radiobutton. This is indeed what I want.
My question is how does it do that? How does it link the object I selected from the table with what appears in modelAttribute?

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller?

Comment: sure, here it is -> [link](http://pastebin.com/9GuND1ci)
what i want to know is what makes the sentenceModelAttribute.getId() return the value from the row i selected in the table. i can't understand how this works.

Comment: Can you post the class file for the sentenceModelAttribute object. I'm expecting it has a 'allSentences' list but what object types are contained in that list. Is it a string or some custom object which contains an 'id' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radiobutton has `id` as the path attribute. This path is relative to `sentenceModelAttribute` which is set in your form tag, so the value of the radiobutton is bound to `sentenceModelAttribute.id`.

Comment: yes, sentenceModelAttribute has a field named id.
so i suppose that for example if i had checkboxes instead of radiobuttons, i would need to make sentenceModelAttribute with a List<long> id instead of just one long id?

Comment: after trying out some stuff i figured it out... it seems that path attribute does magic :)
thanks

Comment: @alegen yes, since there could be several selected values.

Answer (score 1):

It is done with [DataBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

In case of Form POST, it works with [WebDataBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)